# How to disable massaction Dropdown conditionally ui_component Magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, massaction

I have implemented functionality like hiding mass actions based on some conditions. I want to assign some specific rights to other admin users.

I want functionality like, If there is no mass action in the dropdown then it should not visible. But in my case, the dropdown is visible with no option. So can you guys let me know how can I hide mass action dropdown if there is no option?

Please check this screenshot,

[image]

Please check my mass-action code below,

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Sampleproduct\Ui\Component;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface;

class MassAction extends \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction
{

    /**
     * @var AuthorizationInterface
     */
    private $authorization;


    public function __construct(
       ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) 
    {
       
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
        parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
    }

      public function prepare()
    {
        parent::prepare();
        $config = $this->getConfiguration();
        if (isset($config['actions'])) {

        if (!$this->authorization->isAllowed('Namespace_Sampleproduct::delete')) {
            $notAllowedActions = ['delete'];
            $allowedActions = [];
            foreach ($config['actions'] as $action) {
                if (!in_array($action['type'], $notAllowedActions)) {
                    $allowedActions[] = $action;
                }
            }
            $config['actions'] = $allowedActions;
            $this->setData('config', (array)$config);
        }

    }
    }
}
```